# lavary laravel-menu - how to set target blank

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set the target blank on a menu item with laravel-menu but if I call

```
$menu->add( 'external' , array('url' => 'http://example.com', 'target' => '_blank' ) );
```

the output is

```
<li target="_blank"><a href="http://example.com">external</a></li>
```

do you have any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: did you try to call `attr()` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution:

```
$menu->add( 'external link' ,  'https://example.com' )->link->attr( 'target' , '_blank' );
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try :

```
$menu->add( 'external' , array('url' => 'http://example.com' ) );
$menu->external->attr('target', '_blank');

// Or

$menu->external->attr(['target' => '_blank']);
```

Comment: I tried with 
`$menu->add( 'external' , array('url' => 'http://example.com'))->attr('target', '_blank');` but it doesn't work for me